# How to count items in JSON data

Tags: python, json, count, element

How I can get the number of elements in node of JSON data?

**JSON:**

```
{
  "result":[
    {
      "run":[
        {
          "action":"stop"
        },
        {
          "action":"start"
        },
        {
          "action":"start"
        }
      ],
      "find":true
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get the number of elements from node `data['result'][0]['run']`. It should be 3, but I can't find how to do it in Python.

Comment: Come on, show us what you have so far, please.

Comment: I'm guessing you have problems with getting it as a list? the rest is `len(x)`

Comment: Write the code to do it if it was a Python dict. Then we'll tell you how to transform the JSON in Python ;)

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
import json

json_data = json.dumps({
  "result":[
    {
      "run":[
        {
          "action":"stop"
        },
        {
          "action":"start"
        },
        {
          "action":"start"
        }
      ],
      "find": "true"
    }
  ]
})

item_dict = json.loads(json_data)
print len(item_dict['result'][0]['run'])
```

Convert it into Python dictionary

Comment: `loads` or `load`?

Comment: It should be `loads`

Comment: `loads` loads from string while `load` loads from file

Answer (score 24):

You're close.  A really simple solution is just to get the length from the 'run' objects returned. No need to bother with 'load' or 'loads':

```
len(data['result'][0]['run'])
```

Comment: haa liked the name!  hail house atreides

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same task, except that I had to read the data from a JSON file instead of a variable like yours, here is how I did it:

```
import json
with open('movie.json', encoding='utf8') as JSONFile:
    data = json.load(JSONFile)
print(len(data['movie'][0]))
```

and my sample JSON element in the file looks like this:

```
{
"movie": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "Inception",
        "Overview": "Cobb, a skilled thief who commits corporate espionage by infiltrating the subconscious of his targets is offered a chance to regain his old life as payment for a task considered to be impossible: \"inception\", the implantation of another person's idea into a target's subconscious.",
        "Tagline": "Your mind is the scene of the crime.",
        "Budget": 160000000.0000,
        "Revenue": 825532764.0000,
        "ImdbUrl": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt1375666",
        "TmdbUrl": "https:\/\/www.themoviedb.org\/movie\/27205",
        "PosterUrl": "https:\/\/image.tmdb.org\/t\/p\/w342\/\/9gk7adHYeDvHkCSEqAvQNLV5Uge.jpg",
        "BackdropUrl": "https:\/\/image.tmdb.org\/t\/p\/original\/\/s3TBrRGB1iav7gFOCNx3H31MoES.jpg",
        "OriginalLanguage": "en",
        "ReleaseDate": "2010-07-15T00:00:00",
        "RunTime": 148,
        "Price": 9.90,
        "CreatedDate": "2021-04-03T16:51:30.1633333",
        "UpdatedDate": null,
        "UpdatedBy": null,
        "CreatedBy": null,
        "genres": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Adventure"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Action"
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Science Fiction"
            }
        ]
    }]
```